# Flutter, how to implement "Favorites" with local db

Tags: flutter

I would like to implement "Favorite" in my app, with a "favorite" icon inside a data card allowing the user to mark or unmark favorite.  There is function to read the local db to see if the record is marked or not and displaying the corresponding icon.

```
Widget setFavouriteIcon(_id) {
  bool marked = markedFavourites(_id);
  if (marked == true) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
        addFavourites(_id);
      },
      child: Icon(
        size: 24,
        Icons.favorite_border_outlined,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    );
  }else{
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
        removeFavourites(_id);
      },
      child: Icon(
        size: 24,
        Icons.favorite,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

markedFavourites() suppose is an async function to read the local db, but I got a compile error: A value of type 'Future' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool'.

How should I get a bool value from a future?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a `bool` value from your future returning function, you need to `await` it and your function needs to return a `Future<bool>` (future of type bool). Check out what your function return type is, and then `await` it in your code such as `bool marked = await markedFavourites(_id);`. And mark your `setFavouriteIcon(_id)` function `async` such as `Widget setFavouriteIcon(_id) async {`

Comment: Future<Widget> setIcon() async, is not valid

Answer (score -1):

You can get response like :

Future marked = await markedFavourites(_id);
after that just check marked is null or not
after that do same way you are using your code

Comment: I can’t use await because it’s inside a function which returns a widget (outlined or solid heart icon) and future widget is not valid

Answer (score -2):

Yep. you should use with `.then()` or `async` `await` to insert future value to variable.

```
markedFavourites(_id).then((value)
     {bool marked = value}
);
```

Write like that.

Comment: Why give minus? If give minus. Give an explanation.